# Php mkdir 0777 and renaming images on upload

Tags: php

I am having some issues here.  I am trying to create a new folder based on the username in uploads folder. It is not giving and read/write permissions and then before I had that feature in here it renames the images (how can I keep original name).

```
 $username = $_POST['username'];

 $uploads_dir = 'uploads/' . $username;
 if (!is_dir($uploads_dir)) {
   mkdir($uploads_dir, 0777);
 }

 $count = 1;
 foreach ($_FILES["userfile"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
 if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"][$key];
    $name = $_FILES["userfile"]["name"][$key];
    $uploadfile = "$uploads_dir/$name";
    $ext = strtolower(substr($uploadfile,strlen($uploadfile)-3,3));
    if (preg_match("/(jpg|gif|png|bmp)/",$ext)){
        $newfile = "$uploads_dir/".str_pad($count++,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).".".$ext;
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $newfile)){
            $success++;
        }else{
            echo "Couldn't move file: Error Uploading the file. Retry after sometime.\n";
            $fail++;
        }
    }else{
        echo "Invalid Extension.\n";
        $fail++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do not use mode 0777, there never is a reason to.

Comment: done any basic debugging, e.g. checked what `$newfile` is before you try the move call? Plus, while not 100% applicable here, you should NEVER use the user-providded `['name']` value in filesystem operations. You're at least filtering for file extensions, but theoretically you're allowing a malicious user to scribble a file on your server anywhere they want.

Comment: I removed the 0777 and still gives no write permissions.

Comment: Thanks Marc B... Got the name changed.  But still the permissions is not working.

Comment: @arkascha, last digit should always be 0, yes? (0770) there never is a reason to allow something to unknown user)

Comment: Instead of `mkdir($uploads_dir, 0777);` try `mkdir($uploads_dir); chmod($uploads_dir, 0777);` which worked for me. @mrmcg - It's just an extra line of code.

Comment: I don't think you really have a choice »--^

Comment: vp_arth still not working.  this is getting annoying... :(

Answer (score 0):

A directory is normally 755, although depending on how PHP is run (as you/owner, in your group, or as a random user/world) it might have to be 775 or even 777 in order for your program to be able to write to the directory. Presumably this is on a server. Try 755, then 775, and lastly 777. Many servers forbid "world writable" files or directories, and give a 500 error on xx6 or xx7 permissions.